# Connection refused on OPTIONS header in Node/Angular/Express App with nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, proxy, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to get an express app running on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 12.04 droplet with nginx as a reverse proxy, but I'm always getting an **OPTIONS net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** error when I try to POST a form. I've tried a bunch of different nginx configurations and cors settings and it still happens.

Using Node v0.12, Express v4 and latest nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name thepalette.tk;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
}
```

Edit:

I've found the nginx error logs and it says the following:

```
2015/03/05 05:45:15 [error] 6079#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused)
while connecting to upstream, 
client: x.x.x.x, 
server: thepalette.tk, 
request: "GET /register HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://x.x.x.x:3000/register", 
host: "thepalette.tk"
```

Answer (score 0):

use cors middleware for express in your app.js.
For example:

```
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true
}));
```

Comment: It's a problem with the nginx, because my express logs don't even mention the request.